# Navigate to the 'new' object page passing in specific record type Id with LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, record-type, navigation

When I click on the button, a new record is generated, I automatically want that when I click on the button, I navigate to the page of the record I just created, but with this code it does not work with me.

T get this error : Page doesn't exist
Enter a valid URL and try again

```
  @track Name;
    listOptions = [];
    _selected= [];
    @track err;
    @api recordId;


    @wire(getSalesOrg)
    
    getSalesOrg({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            let option = [];
            data.forEach(element => {
                option.push({ label: element.label, value: element.value });
                
            });
            this.listOptions = option;
        } else if (error) {
            console.log('error  : ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    }
    get selected() {
        return this._selected.length ? this._selected : 'none';
    }
    handleChange(e) {
        this._selected = e.detail.value;


        
    }

 

    recordPageUrl;
 Fun(){
        getMethode({TemplateId: this.recordId, Value : this._selected.toString()})
        
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                objectApiName: 'Form__c',
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        })
        
    .then(result => 
        console.log(result)
        )
        .catch(err =>
             console.log(JSON.stringify(err)))
      
    }
```

=>HTML

```
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={Fun}>Go To New Record</button>
```

=> Apex :

```
  @AuraEnabled 
  public static void getFormTemplateName(Id TemplateId, string sapValue){
  Form_Template__c newFormTemplate = new Form_Template__c();
    Form_Template__c formTemplate = [SELECT Id ,Name,RecordTypeId,Form_Template_ID__c FROM Form_Template__c 
                                                  WHERE Id =:TemplateId];
   Sales__c salesOrg = [SELECT Id,Name from Sales__c where SAP_Sales_Org_Code__c =: sapValue];                                              

   
    newFormTemplate.RecordTypeId = formTemplate.RecordTypeId;
    newFormTemplate.Name = formTemplate.Name;
    newFormTemplate.Form_Template_ID__c = sapValue+'-'+formTemplate.Name;
    newFormTemplate.Sales__c = salesOrg.Id;

    insert newFormTemplate;

    
  }
```

Comment: Can you check recordId variable is correct and has value in it.

Comment: @Elijah ? YES I CHECHED THE VARIABLE AND IT CONTAIN A VALUE

Comment: @Elijah , I used `    console.log('record id is:'+this.recordId); ` and I verified , I get the value of the recordId  actuel , I don't get the recordId of the new record , what I want is to get the recordId of the new one that I just created , I think that this is the problem , do you now any solution to fixed ?

Comment: add snippet of code from where your new record is getting craeted.

Comment: @Elijah , I added the all code in my post .